# Conditionally Add Checkbox to handsontable

Tags: jquery, handsontable

how to add conditional formatting for a checkbox.
EX: i have 13 columns and 4000 rows if a row has data in atleast one column add checkbox to first cell. If all the cells in a row have data then check that check box. The checkbox Should have id also.

I will get data like

```
[["<input type='checkbox' name='1'","a","a","a","a","a"...],
["<input type='checkbox' name='2'","a","a","a","a","a"...],
["<input type='checkbox' name='3'","a","a","a","a","a"...]....];
```

I need to load that and if user do any deletion or updations of cells i need to check the checkbox status.
I am using 
Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this on load...

```
// run through each row in the table
checkCellsForStuff = $('#myTable tr').each(function() {
    var cellHasStuff = 0;

    // check each cell in the current row
    $('td', this).each(function() {
        if ($(this).text()) { cellHasStuff = 1 }
    });

    // add a checkbox to the first cell in the current row
    if (cellHasStuff = 1) {
        $(this).('td').first().html('<input type="checkbox">');
    }
});
```

Then, for clicks...

```
$('#myTable td').blur(function() {
    checkCellsForStuff();
});
```

This is untested, but should get you started.

Comment: hi thanks for ur response. That is one way but i am searching for any rendering kind of format. Beacuse the above is giving performance issue for 4000 rows and 13 columns..

Comment: And one more thing i have to add checkbox in the time of loading the handsontable..

Comment: The first part does the check and add on load.